# DropDownList set selected item to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added DropDownList in ASP.net.

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" > 
<asp:ListItem Text="Name" Value="jsh" Selected="true" /> 
<asp:ListItem Text="hhh" Value="sds"/> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Instead on saying `Selected="true"` in ASP.net i want to set the selected item using C# inside the

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DropDownList1 // THE SELECTED ITEM NEEDS TO BE SET TO TRUE
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

UPDATE

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_onChanged"> 

</asp:DropDownList>
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("En", "en-US"));
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Fr", "fr-FR"));
}

}
```

// I also copied `InitializeCulture()`

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() 
{

string Kultur = "en-US"; 
if (Session["lang"] != null)
{


    Kultur = Session["lang"].ToString();
}


this.UICulture = Kultur;
this.Culture = Kultur;
base.InitializeCulture();


}
```

//

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
  Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If the user selected it, it is already selected. So i assume that you actually want to set an underlying record's field to `true`, but we don't know your schema,rdbms, etc.

Comment: There's no DB involved. I am refreshing the page in the SelectedIndexChanged method. So i need to set the selected value to true so it will get affected in the UI. or else when i refresh i will not get the selected value but the default value will be selected

Comment: You don't have to refresh the page yourself if you set `AutoPostBack="True"`. A PostBack won't clear your selected value in the DropDownList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Your question doesnot make sence.  If the user selected it, it is already selected. When you refresh the page the `DropDownList1` is again loading values. So you the `DropDownList1` selected item would be lost

You can do like this,

In `aspx` file

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

In `aspx.cs` file

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Name", "jsh"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("hhh", "sds"));
        }
    }
```

Below code is to select the item

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
```

or

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;
```

or

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Selected = true;
```

Comment: But after i refresh the page it still displays index 0 of the DropDownList. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: for that you have to set ddl value in viewstate. ddl value will be reset every time on page refresh.

Comment: @AshfaqShaikh: You cannot use ViewState when you use `Response.Redirect`. Then you need to use `Session` or a query string parameter.

Comment: hey sharonHwk you can do in this way
if(Session["ddl"]==null){
  Session["ddl"]=DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
if(Session["ddl"]!=null)
{
 DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(convert.tostring(Session["ddl"])).Selected = true;
}

Comment: @AshfaqShaikh you want me to add this code in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged ` ? and what is `convert ` ?

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi i did try your code but it was the same. Shall i paste my latest code in the post ?

Comment: Ok give me a min. let me paste it

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "value";

Or

DropDownList1.SelectedIndex= 1;
```

Comment: The name Value does not exist in the current context. How to solve this ?

Comment: you should give value or index of the item which you want to set true

Answer (score 0):

you can also make selection in this way.

```
if (ddl.Items.FindByValue("value") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty("value"))
{
  ddl.Items.FindByValue("value").Selected = true;
}
```